# Bootstrap - Align brand logo and options menu(icon + text) of navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I do not get to align the brand logo and the text and image icons to the navigation bar to use bootstrap enviroiment.

The problem is the logo is outside botton of the navigation bar and the icon not align with the text.

Please could you help me?

Te code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Web Testing</title>

        <!-- INCLUDES -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>          
            <!-- NAVIGATION -->

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="container-fluid"> 
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.es"><img src="assets/images/brandlogo.png"/></a></div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active marges-opciones-right" ><a href="produccio.php"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px">work</i> Page1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li class="text-options marges-opciones-right"><a href="imatges.php"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px">collections</i> Page2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown marges-opciones-left"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px" >face</i><span class="username"> Username </span><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 40px" >list</i></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><span class="glyphicon"></span><i class="material-icons">settings</i>  preferències</a></li>
                        <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><span class="glyphicon"></span><i class="material-icons">lock</i>  canviar password</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>   
                        <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:18px">power_settings_new</i>  log out</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </nav>
```

The css is default of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add these properties to align them in the same line:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: It's perfect. I'm going to try it. Thank

Comment: Sure.. Happy to help!

Comment: It's working fine to content items(options menu icon+text) but the brand logo is not align to bottom to the base itself. I would want the logo full in all area to the navigation bar.

Comment: i think you need to set the height of the navbar brand..make it like height: 70px; ...It is set default to height:50px;

Comment: I have changed the height of the navbar-brand in the css file to 70px but the logo isn't move it :(

Comment: Ok, it's working fine. The problem was with the padding values. Thanks so much.

Comment: @ruzD: You should learn to inspect and debug your code...Great to know it worked...:)